# How to place an object in a specific location (x,y) on a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

How can I place an object in a specific location (x,y) on a JFrame?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here find the [Absolute Positioning Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html). Please do read carefully, as to why this approach is discouraged over using [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

To add say a JButton to your JPanel, you can use this :

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
button.setBounds(5, 5, 50, 30);
panel.add(button);
```

Here try this example program :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AbsoluteLayoutExample
{
    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Absolute Layout Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel label = new JLabel(
            "This JPanel uses Absolute Positioning"
                                    , JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setSize(300, 30);
        label.setLocation(5, 5);

        JButton button = new JButton("USELESS");
        button.setSize(100, 30);
        button.setLocation(95, 45);

        contentPane.add(label);
        contentPane.add(button);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(310, 125);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new AbsoluteLayoutExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Absolute Positioning Output]

Comment: what is this "pane"? can I use JPanel instead?

Comment: @user1441845 : DO watch this latest edit, how you can use it with `JPanel` :-) I forgot to tell you before, that you have to write `panel.setLayout(null)`, though I had mentioned that in this code example now :-)

Comment: for AbsoluteLayout is required to use Insets, not sure if Bounds are correct way +1

Comment: @mKorbel : IMHO, setBounds() is used in place of setSize()/setLocation() as a shortcut, instead of using them, we can use setBounds(), since the 1st argument is for X-Axis, 2nd for Y-Axis, 3rd for WIDTH and 4th for HEIGHT.

Comment: @nIcE cOw as a shortcut :-) :-) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @user1441845 : Ahha, as per the new comment by @mKorbel, I just realized, he is too true in pointing that out, do use `setSize(width, height) and setLocation(x, y)`, to place your components on the said Co-ordinates. So edited my answer likewise :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try these 2... in combination with each other...

`setLocation()` and `setBounds()`

Its even better to use GroupLayout, developed by NetBeans team in 2005. WindowsBuilder Pro is a good tool for Building Gui in java

Comment: +1, wish I could grasp GroupLayout, no doubt one of THE BEST Layout Managers around

Comment: @nIcEcOw: tinkering in the NetBeans GUI editor and examining the generated code is one way to experiment with `GroupLayout`.

Comment: @trashgod : Interesting idea, drag/drop on the IDE, to experiment and play with the code, the usual way. That's one wonderful piece of advice, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this absolute layout code sample:

[Absolute Layout demo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AbsoluteLayoutDemo.htm)

Comment: +1, I had seen this tutorial somewhere else, just cann't remember where :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the class inheriting the frame:

```
setLayout(null);
```

In your component:

```
setLocation(x,y);
```

Comment: Concerns: 1) you need to set the layout of the JFrame's contentPane, not the JFrame itself. 2) If the container's layout is null, then the coder is totally responsible for both the location *and* the size of the components that are added. 3) You should add a caveat about avoiding use of null layout and absolute positioning.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : BULL'S EYE! I missed that JFrame part, what you caught so easily :-)